# Using GStreamer in C++ with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gstreamer, extern

Is it possible to use GStreamer C binding in C++ project?

When I compile GStreamer HelloWorld [sample](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) in C++ VS enviroment, gst_init() gets mangled to _gst_init() and then linker is unable to find the function in GStreamer .lib. The same also happens with other GStreamer functions.

I've tried to enclose include directive with "*extern C*" declaration like this:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <gst/gst.h>
}
```

but it was of no help.

Can I tell to the compiler how exactly to mangle the names? Is there any C++ wrapper for GStreamer, or I need to write one, in order to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried this long ago I ran into problems as well, I guess gstreamer and glib are not really VS-friendly.

You can try [OSSBuild's version](https://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/), it provides binaries, solution files, and even some patches to build gstreamer with Visual Studio.

I personally wound up compiling gstreamer and glib with MinGW/GCC instead, and it was still usable with Visual Studio. As for a C++ wrapper, take a look at [gstreamermm](https://developer.gnome.org/gstreamermm/0.10/).